# How can I hide "Emergency mode" on Samsung without Root?

Tags: android-7.0-nougat

How can I hide or lock "Emergency mode" found in the Power Menu on the Samsung (Android 7.0) **without** rooting the phone?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: So far the only way I found how to change the stock Power Menu was to root the phone, install Xposed and NeoPowerMenu and remove "Emergency Mode". Is there not an easier way to change the stock Power Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to disable Emergency Mode without root. Enable Developer Mode and USB debugging mode then on a terminal input the following line of code:

adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.android.emergencymode.service

Hope this helps!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to do that without root, because the power menu options are "hardcoded" inside the framework rom Resource values and you need root privileges to edit it :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to at least put a password on the "Emergency mode"? I don't understand why they would had a feature that can now bypass the phone's security. I can understand to call 9-1-1 but to allow the ability to use all other apps is unnecessary....

Comment: googling for Emergency mode i found that link (https://www.samsung.com/sa_en/support/mobile-devices/galaxy-note4-how-to-deactivate-the-emergency-mode/) is what are you searching for? The answer of your second question should be no... but seems that samsung edits his firmware to allow you enable/diasble that option (i've not a samsung so i cannot try it).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Legion. You can only disabling Emergency Mode once you're in Emergency Mode. I want to prevent people from evening going into Emergency Mode. Currently any stranger can pick up a Samsung phone (that is locked) press the power button and enter Emergency Mode. Then they can use your data/apps etc.